# PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2

Tags: flutter, static, static-data

I am using this function for read and write the local json, to change data dynamically in flutter

Future getMetaData(FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig) async {

Map<String, dynamic> newMetaData = json.decode(remoteConfig.getValue("meta_data").asString());

```
File file = File("lib/utils/common/meta_api_data.json");
Map<String, dynamic> existingMetaData = {};

try {
  String fileContent = await file.readAsString();
  existingMetaData = json.decode(fileContent);
} catch (e) {
  print('Error reading file: $e');
}
existingMetaData.addAll(newMetaData);
await file.writeAsString(json.encode(existingMetaData));
```

}

I am getting this error

Error reading file: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'lib/utils/common/meta_api_data.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

I am trying to fetch data from the local json and updating with server json on fly

for example
my local json-->

{
"title": "Stack Over"
}

my server response-->

{
"title": "Stack Over Flow"
}

after I updated successfully.

I am expecting my local json will be-->
{
"title": "Stack Over Flow"
}